# Get ceiling integer from number in linux (BASH)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ceil

How would I do something like:

```
ceiling(N/500)
```

N representing a number.

But in a linux Bash script

Comment: A solution for the Bash is given at Unix & Linux: [Convert a float to the next integer up as opposed to the nearest](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168476/convert-a-float-to-the-next-integer-up-as-opposed-to-the-nearest)

Comment: Beware: All answers here that are based on the shell arithmetic expansion `$(( ... ))` fail when the operands are already floating point numbers. E.g. `echo $((1.1))` yields: `-bash: 1.1: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".1")` before even attempting any division.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Why use external script languages? You get floor by default. To get ceil, do

```
$ divide=8; by=3; (( result=(divide+by-1)/by )); echo $result
3
$ divide=9; by=3; (( result=(divide+by-1)/by )); echo $result
3
$ divide=10; by=3; (( result=(divide+by-1)/by )); echo $result
4
$ divide=11; by=3; (( result=(divide+by-1)/by )); echo $result
4
$ divide=12; by=3; (( result=(divide+by-1)/by )); echo $result
4
$ divide=13; by=3; (( result=(divide+by-1)/by )); echo $result
5
....
```

To take negative numbers into account you can beef it up a bit. Probably cleaner ways out there but for starters

```
$ divide=-10; by=10; neg=; if [ $divide -lt 0 ]; then (( divide=-divide )); neg=1; fi; (( result=(divide+by-1)/by )); if [ $neg ]; then (( result=-result )); fi; echo $result
-1

$ divide=10; by=10; neg=; if [ $divide -lt 0 ]; then (( divide=-divide )); neg=1; fi; (( result=(divide+by-1)/by )); if [ $neg ]; then (( result=-result )); fi; echo $result
1
```

(Edited to switch `let ...` to `(( ... ))`.)

Comment: Nice one, by solving with a mathematical characteristic.

Comment: doesn't work for negative numbers `echo $(((-10+10-1)/10))` gives zero, not -1

Comment: Good catch. Added an example that is probably not ideal but works around the issue.

Comment: What do you mean when you write "You get floor by default"? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @ColinMaudry Integer division gives you the floor value. Try echo $((7/4))

Comment: Be aware that `bash` only supports fixed-size integers; `$divide + $by - 1` is subject to overflow.

Answer (score 19):

Call out to a scripting language with a ceil function.  Given `$NUMBER`:

```
python -c "from math import ceil; print ceil($NUMBER/500.0)"
```

or

```
perl -w -e "use POSIX; print ceil($NUMBER/500.0), qq{\n}"
```

Comment: In Perl, wouldn't you use: `ceil($ARGV[0]/$ARGV[1])` to use the two script arguments?  And then you'd use single quotes around the script.  Or, using double quotes you can let the shell substitute its $1, $2.

Comment: Sure, yeah, <code>perl -w -e 'use POSIX; print ceil($ARGV[0]/$ARGV[1]), qq{\n}' $N 500</code> is fine too, etc.  TMTOWTDI.  The important bit is using a standards-based ceil implementation.

Comment: Code tag fail?  I'm new here.  :(

Comment: Haha, yeah you can't code code in the comments :( but doesn't matter, I prefer to use Python anyway :) Thanks for the code!

Comment: The language requested was bash, and therefore should be a bash shell script that doesn't require the use of any other language. I do not believe that this should be the top answer.

Comment: @DCurro, fixed, though at the time I asked the question there was no pure bash solution, so I picked the one that worked best for me.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a solution using bc (which should be installed just about everywhere):

```
ceiling_divide() {
  ceiling_result=`echo "($1 + $2 - 1)/$2" | bc`
}
```

Here's another purely in bash:

```
# Call it with two numbers.
# It has no error checking.
# It places the result in a global since return() will sometimes truncate at 255.

# Short form from comments (thanks: Jonathan Leffler)
ceiling_divide() {
  ceiling_result=$((($1+$2-1)/$2))
}

# Long drawn out form.
ceiling_divide() {
  # Normal integer divide.
  ceiling_result=$(($1/$2))
  # If there is any remainder...
  if [ $(($1%$2)) -gt 0 ]; then
    # rount up to the next integer
    ceiling_result=$((ceiling_result + 1))
  fi
  # debugging
  # echo $ceiling_result
}
```

Comment: You can simplify that to remove the conditional stuff: `ceiling_result=$((($1+$2-1)/$2))`

Comment: @1ch1g0 He said in Bash. There's no floating point in bash. His example showed integers as well and he wants an integer result. Anyway, I added a solution that uses bc. It'll handle the floating point numbers.

Answer (score 6):

You can use awk

```
#!/bin/bash
number="$1"
divisor="$2"
ceiling() {
  awk -vnumber="$number" -vdiv="$divisor" '
  function ceiling(x){return x%1 ? int(x)+1 : x}
  BEGIN{ print ceiling(number/div) }'
}
ceiling
```

output

```
$ ./shell.sh 1.234 500
1
```

Or if there's a choice, you can use a better shell that
does floating point, eg Zsh

```
integer ceiling_result
ceiling_divide() {
  ceiling_result=$(($1/$2))
  echo $((ceiling_result+1))
}

ceiling_divide 1.234 500
```

Comment: Certainly the computation for ZSH is not correct.  `$1/$2` may be exact.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding a bit on [Kalle's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12536521/624066), here's the algorithm nicely packed in a function:

```bash
ceildiv() {
    local num=$1
    local div=$2
    echo $(( (num + div - 1) / div ))
}
```

or as a one-liner:

```bash
ceildiv(){ echo $((($1+$2-1)/$2)); }
```

If you want to get fancy, you could use a more robust version validates input to check if they're numerical, also handles negative numbers:

```bash
ceildiv() {
    local num=${1:-0}
    local div=${2:-1}
    if ! ((div)); then
        return 1
    fi
    if ((num >= 0)); then
        echo $(( (num + div - 1) / div ))
    else
        echo $(( -(-num + div - 1) / div ))
    fi
}
```

This uses a "fake" ceil for negative numbers, to the highest *absolute* integer, ie, -10 / 3 = -4 and not -3 as it should, as -3 > -4. If you want a "true" ceil, use `$(( num / div ))` instead after the `else`

And then use it like:

```
$ ceildiv 10 3
4
$ ceildiv 501 500
2
$ ceildiv 0 3
0
$ ceildiv -10 1
-10
$ ceildiv -10 3
-4
```

Answer (score 4):

Mathematically, the function of ceiling can be define with floor, ceiling(x) = -floor(-x). And, floor is the default when converting a positive float to integer.

```
if [ $N -gt 0 ]; then expr 1 - $(expr $(expr 1 - $N) / 500); else expr $N / 500; fi
```

Ref. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please include an explanation for your code, as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Comment: Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Not correct when the number is a whole number ... floor (500 + 1) = floor (501) = 501 != ceiling (500)

Comment: @MartinJaniczek Thank you for pointing out the error. After reviewing the definition of ceiling and floor, my answer get updated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) if you have it installed. It's "sed for JSON", but I find it surprisingly handy for simple tasks like this too.

Examples:

```
$ echo 10.001 | jq '.|ceil'
11

$ jq -n '-10.001 | ceil'
-10
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Floor () {
  DIVIDEND=${1}
  DIVISOR=${2}
  RESULT=$(( ( ${DIVIDEND} - ( ${DIVIDEND} % ${DIVISOR}) )/${DIVISOR} ))
  echo ${RESULT}
}
R=$( Floor 8 3 )
echo ${R}
```

```
Ceiling () {
  DIVIDEND=${1}
  DIVISOR=${2}
  $(( ( ( ${DIVIDEND} - ( ${DIVIDEND} % ${DIVISOR}) )/${DIVISOR} ) + 1 ))
  echo ${RESULT}
}
R=$( Ceiling 8 3 )
echo ${R}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string representation of a decimal number, `bash` does support ceiling using `printf` function like this:

```sh
$ printf %.4f 0.12345
0.1235
```

But if you need to do some math using decimals, you can use `bc -l` that by default scales to 20 decimals, then use the result with `printf` to round it.

```
printf %.3f $(echo '(5+50*3/20 + (19*2)/7 )' | bc -l)
17.929
```

Comment: `printf` rounds to nearest, this answer is wrong without `+/-0.5` shenanigans.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution using Awk:

If you want the ceil of ($a/$b)  use

```
echo "$a $b" | awk '{print int( ($1/$2) + 1 )}'
```

and the floor use

```
echo "$a $b" | awk '{print int($1/$2)}'
```

Note that I just echo the dividend '$a' as the first field of the line to awk and the divisor '$b' as the second.

Comment: int( ($1/$2) + 1 ) != ceil($1/$2) if $1/$2 is integer!

Comment: This is wrong. Your ceil method will return the wrong results for divisions with no remainder. For example 2/2 is one (and no remainder) and ceil(1) should return 1. Your method returns 2.

Answer (score 0):

Some more concise Awk logic

```
awk '
function ceil(ip) {
  print ip%1 ? int(ip)+1 : ip
}  
BEGIN {
  ceil(1000/500)
  ceil(1001/500)
}
'
```

Result

```
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Some more concise Awk logic

```
awk '
function ceil(ip) {
  print ip%1 ? int(ip)+1 : ip
}  
BEGIN {
  ceil(1000/500)
  ceil(1001/500)
}
'
```

Result

```
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

This function wont't add 1, if the division returns a non-floating number.

```
function ceiling {
    DIVIDEND=${1}
    DIVISOR=${2}
    if [ $(( DIVIDEND % DIVISOR )) -gt 0 ]; then
            RESULT=$(( ( ( $DIVIDEND - ( $DIVIDEND % $DIVISOR ) ) / $DIVISOR ) + 1 ))
    else
            RESULT=$(( $DIVIDEND / $DIVISOR ))
    fi
    echo $RESULT
}
```

Use it like this:

```
echo $( ceiling 100 33 )
> 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the gorgeous 'printf' [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356698/how-to-remove-decimal-from-a-variable) will round up to the next integer

```
printf %.0f $float
or
printf %.0f `your calculation formula`
or
printf %.0f $(your calculation formula)
```

ref: [how to remove decimal from a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356698/how-to-remove-decimal-from-a-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Without specifying any function, we can use the following awk script:

```
echo x y | awk '{ r=$1 % $2; q=$1/y; if (r != 0) q=int(q+1); print q}'
```

Not sure this one get any logical error or not.  Please correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already familiar with the Python library, then rather than learn `bc`, you might want to define this bash function:

```sh
pc () { pyexpr="from math import *; print($@)"; python -c "$pyexpr"; }
```

Then:

```sh
pc "ceil(3/4)"
1
```

but also any valid python *expression* works:

```sh
pc pi / 4
0.7853981633974483

pc "'\n'.join(['Pythagoras said that %3.2f^2 + %3.2f^2 is always %3.2f'
    % (sin(ai), cos(ai), sin(ai)**2 + cos(ai)**2)
    for ai in [pi / 4 * k for k in range(8)]])"
Pythagoras said that 0.00^2 + 1.00^2 is always 1.00
Pythagoras said that 0.71^2 + 0.71^2 is always 1.00
Pythagoras said that 1.00^2 + 0.00^2 is always 1.00
Pythagoras said that 0.71^2 + -0.71^2 is always 1.00
Pythagoras said that 0.00^2 + -1.00^2 is always 1.00
Pythagoras said that -0.71^2 + -0.71^2 is always 1.00
Pythagoras said that -1.00^2 + -0.00^2 is always 1.00
Pythagoras said that -0.71^2 + 0.71^2 is always 1.00
```