# What is the difference between source and export?

Tags: linux, unix

I am writing a shell script, to read a file which has key=value pair and set those variables as environment variables. But I have a doubt, if I do `source file.txt` will that set the variables defined in that file as environment variable or I should read the file line by line and set it using export command ?

Is source command in this case different than export?

Comment: what shell are you using?

Comment: I would be very wary of `source`-ing a user-defined file in a shell script in a production environment. Imagine a disgruntled employee adding the line `rm -rf ${HOME}` (or worse)...

Comment: Related, and very helpful and more-detailed: https://askubuntu.com/questions/862236/source-vs-export-vs-export-ld-library-path/862256#862256

Comment: @johnsyweb This is why we have code reviews. Besides that, all that does is delete prod, it would just need a new deploy. It's not really good approach to not use something just because there's potential danger. The "disgruntled employee" could do many other worse things like mangle DB data or email registered customers bad messages or security info.

Answer (score 50):

When you `source` the file, the assignments will be set but the variables are not exported unless the `allexport` option has been set.  If you want all the variables to be exported, it is much simpler to use `allexport` and `source` the file than it is to read the file and use `export` explicitly.  In other words, you should do:

```
set -a
. file.txt
```

(I prefer `.` because it is more portable than `source`, but `source` works just fine in `bash`.)

Note that exporting a variable does not make it an environment variable.  It just makes it an environment variable in any subshell.

Comment: `Note that exporting a variable does not make it an environment variable. It just makes it an environment variable in any subshell.` So 1) what is an environment variable? And 2) how do you make a variable an environment variable?

Comment: For most cases, it doesn't really matter if a variable is in the environment or not.  Environment variables will be inherited by all subprocesses, as will non-environment variables that have been exported.  As to "what is an environment variable?"...it is a variable that is in the environment!  For practical purposes in the shell, this just means that it is a variable that was inherited from its parent when the shell was invoked.  Some families of shell provide an explicit `setenv` function to put a variable in the environment, but not all do.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Note that I've added an answer and provided additional explanations and examples of `export` and `source` (`.`) which I think are very useful, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62626515/4561887. I keep forgetting what these things mean myself after not writing bash scripts for a while, so I made my answer what I call "canonical", meaning it's an answer I plan to come back to again and again myself each time I forget a detail or need a refresher.

Comment: This is a good idea for anyone who needs to pass lots of env to make file.

Answer (score 31):

### `source` (`.`) vs `export` (and also some file lock [`flock`] stuff at the end)

### In short

1. `source some_script.sh`, or the POSIX-compliant equivalent, `. some_script.sh`, *brings variables in* from other scripts, while
2. `export my_var="something"` *pushes variables out to other scripts/processes* which are called/started from the current script/process.

Using `source some_script.sh` or `. some_script.sh` in a Linux shell script is kind of like using `import some_module` in Python, or `#include <some_header_file.h>` in C or C++. **It brings variables in from the script being sourced.**

Using `export some_var="something"` is kind of like setting that variable locally, so it is available for the rest of the current script or process, and then **also** passing it in to any and all sub-scripts or processes you may call from this point onward.

### More details

So, this:

```bash
# export `some_var` so that it is set and available in the current
# script/process, as well as in all sub-scripts or processes which are called
# from the current script/process
export some_var="something"
# call other scripts/processes, passing in `some_var` to them automatically
# since it was just exported above! 
script1.sh  # this script now gets direct access to `some_var`
script2.sh  # as does this one
script3.sh  # and this one
```

is *as though* you had done this:

```bash
# set this variable for the current script/process only
some_var="something" 
# call other scripts/processes, passing in `some_var` to them **manually**
# so they can use it too 
some_var="something" script1.sh  # manually pass in `some_var` to this script
some_var="something" script2.sh  # manually pass in `some_var` to this script
some_var="something" script3.sh  # manually pass in `some_var` to this script
```

except that the first version above, where we called `export some_var="something"` actually has a recursive passing or exporting of variables to sub-processes, so if we call `script1.sh` from inside our current script/process, then `script1.sh` will get the exported variables from our current script, and if `script1.sh` calls `script5.sh`, and `script5.sh` calls `script10.sh`, then both of those scripts as well will get the exported variables automatically. This is *in contrast to the manual case above* where only those scripts called explicitly with manually-set variables as the scripts are called will get them, so sub-scripts will NOT automatically get any variables from their calling scripts!

### How to "un-export" a variable

Note that once you've exported a variable, calling `unset` on it will "unexport it", like this:

```bash
# set and export `some_var` so that sub-processes will receive it
export some_var="something"
script1.sh  # this script automatically receives `some_var`

# unset and un-export `some_var` so that sub-processes will no longer receive it
unset some_var
script1.sh  # this script does NOT automatically receive `some_var`
```

### In summary

1. `source` or `.` *imports*.
2. `export` *exports*.
3. `unset` *unexports*.

### Example

Create this script:

**source_and_export.sh**:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "var1 = $var1"
var2="world"
```

Then mark it executable:

```bash
chmod +x source_and_export.sh
```

Now here is me running some commands at the terminal to test the `source` (`.`) and `export` commands with this script. Type in the command you see after the lines beginning with `$` (not including the comments). The other lines are the output. Run the commands sequentially, one command at a time:

```bash
$ echo "$var1"              # var1 contains nothing locally.

$ var1="hello"              # Set var1 to something in the current process 
                            # only.
$ ./source_and_export.sh    # Call a sub-process.
var1 =                      # The sub-process can't see what I just set var1 
                            # to.
$ export var1               # **Export** var1 so sub-processes will receive it.
$ ./source_and_export.sh    # Call a sub-process.
var1 = hello                # Now the sub-process sees what I previously set 
                            # var1 to.
$ echo "$var1 $var2"        # But, I (my terminal) can't see var2 from the 
                            # subprocess/subscript.
hello 
$ . ./source_and_export.sh  # **Source** the sub-script to _import_ its var2 
                            # into the current process.
var1 = hello
$ echo "$var1 $var2"        # Now I CAN see what the subprocess set var2 to 
                            # because I **sourced it!**
hello world                 # BOTH var1 from the current process and var2 from 
                            # the sub-process print in the current process!
$ unset var1                # Unexport (`unset`) var1.
$ echo "$var1"              # var1 is now NOT set in the current process.
$ ./source_and_export.sh    # And the sub-process doesn't receive it either.
var1 = 
$ var1="hey"                # Set var1 again in the current process.
$ . ./source_and_export.sh  # If I **source** the script, it runs in the 
                            # current process, so it CAN see var1 from the 
                            # current process!
var1 = hey                  # Notice it prints.
$ ./source_and_export.sh    # But if I run the script as a sub-process, it can 
                            # NOT see var1 now because it was `unset` 
                            # (unexported) above and has NOT been `export`ed 
                            # again since then!
var1 =                      # So, var1 is not exported to the subprocess.
$
```

### Using files as global variables between processes

Sometimes, when writing scripts to launch programs and things especially, I have come across cases where `export` doesn't seem to work right. In these cases, sometimes one must resort to *using files themselves as global variables to pass information from one program to another*. Here is how that can be done. In this example, the existence of the file `~/temp/.do_something` functions as an inter-process boolean variable:

```bash
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# In program A, if the file "~/temp/.do_something" does NOT exist, 
# then create it
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mkdir -p ~/temp
if [ ! -f ~/temp/.do_something ]; then
    touch ~/temp/.do_something  # create the file
fi


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# In program B, check to see if the file exists, and act accordingly
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

mkdir -p ~/temp
DO_SOMETHING="false"
if [ -f ~/temp/.do_something ]; then
    DO_SOMETHING="true"
fi

if [ "$DO_SOMETHING" == "true" ] && [ "$SOME_OTHER_VAR" == "whatever" ]; then 
    # remove this global file "variable" so we don't act on it again
    # until "program A" is called again and re-creates the file
    rm ~/temp/.do_something 
    do_something
else
    do_something_else
fi
```

Simply checking for the *existence* of a file, as shown above, works great for globally passing around boolean conditions between programs and processes. However, if you need to pass around more complicated variables, such as strings or numbers, you may need to do this by *writing these values into the file*. In such cases, you should use the *file lock* function, `flock`, to properly ensure inter-process synchronization. It is a type of process-safe (ie: "inter-process") mutex primitive. You can read about it here:

1. The shell script `flock` command: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/flock.1.html. See also `man flock` or `man 1 flock`.
2. The Linux library C command: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html. See also `man 2 flock`. You must `#include <sys/file.h>` in your C file to use this function.

### References

1. [Ask Ubuntu: source vs export vs export LD_LIBRARY_PATH](https://askubuntu.com/a/862256/327339)
2. My own experimentation and testing.
3. I'll be adding the above example to my project on GitHub here, under the `bash` folder: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world

### See also

1. [My personal website article on "How do you write, import, use, and test libraries in Bash?"](https://gabrielstaples.com/bash-libraries/#gsc.tab=0)

   This talks more about sourcing files with the `.` operator, and how to make the file *not* run if you source it, by using this fancy Python-like magic:

   ```bash
   if [ "$__name__" = "__main__" ]; then
       main "$@"
   fi
   ```
2. My answer on [Importing functions from a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76241268/4561887)
3. My answer on [What is the bash equivalent to Python's `if __name__ == '__main__'`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70662116/4561887)

Comment: Awesome explanation! The `import` and `#include` along with the "passing it in to any and all sub-scripts or processes you may call from this point onward" really helped clear up the concept!

Comment: Thanks for the note! Glad you find it useful. I forget this stuff all the time too and literally come back here and reference my own answer regularly as well. I write things down so I can come back to them later.

Comment: And here I am again...reading my own answer. I got confused about what `export` did again and when I must use it, and how to pass variables into scripts you are calling--and I just saw the answer in my answer! Ex: `some_var="something" script1.sh  # manually pass in 'some_var' to this script`.