# Converting from *.hex to *.bin for ARM on Linux

Tags: linux, binary, hex, file-conversion, stm32f4discovery

I want to upload program to my STM32F4 Discovery board using `st-flash` command.
Problem is when I try to upload *.hex or *.elf file it is just not working.
I tried many ways ( like using xxd ) of converting from *.elf or *.hex to *.bin but it is still not working when I upload it. And yes, I tried uploading hex file from other Windows computer and it works.

Sample ( first three lines, just to show you how it looks inside ) of hex file:

```
:020000040800F2
:100000000000022099020008A1020008A5020008D1
:10001000A9020008AD020008B102000800000000BB
```

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 21):

I assume you have linux and you have installed `binutils`, so you just do:

```
objcopy --input-target=ihex --output-target=binary code00.hex code00.bin
```

Comment: Beware: this garbles the loading base address. Will work for OPs case though, as the ihex data bytes start at 0000. Also, any toolchain is good for this operation, not necessarily ARM.

Comment: @ulidtko: 1. the question is for ARM, hence the answer is for ARM; 2. the bin files do not contain loading base address which you claim will be garbled. you specify the address when you load the .bin

Comment: How do you change the start segment address? I don't want it to base itself at 0x00000000 but instead 0x80000000 for example.

Comment: This copies to raw (bare metal) binary, not to ELF.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using arm-none-linux-gnueabi-objcopy (or similar) instead of xxd?
This can be found in any ARM toolchain.

Comment: Yes I have, but there is a possibility I did it wrong way.  Now I am away from my computer. (using my mobile to post it) I think i used something like `arm-none-eabi-objcopy myhex.hex -O binary mybin.bin` but I'm not sure now. I'll let you know when I come home.

Comment: Ok, I can access my PC now. So I've tried both options: `arm-none-eabi-objcopy "F4 Discovery test.elf" -Obinary "out.bin"` and `arm-none-eabi-objcopy "F4 Discovery test.elf" -Oihex "newout.bin"` - they don't work, at least for me. I'm actually trying to understand OpenOCD and I've uploaded my *.hex and it works...

Comment: perhaps you have to name it ending with `.hex`

Answer (score 2):

`.hex` file format is documented on the web.  You need a loader program capable to understand it, as it has several kinds of registers to control the loading process.  Some of the registers control entry point address. Others are data to be loaded at some fixed address.

You can get information at the wikipedia (I have found it there) for Intel Hex format (that's how it is called).  If all the data is on only one segment and no entry point is specified, theoretically you can convert it to binary data to be loaded, but that's improbable.

It is a text file made of lines beginning with ':' character, then comes a two field hex number representing the number of bytes of data this record has, then the address this data is to be loaded on, then the type of file, it can be one of:

- **00** This value is for a bunch of data, normally 16 bytes (0x10)
- **01** End of file. It has no data, so always is codified as :00000001FF
- **02** Extended segment address, to allow addresses with more than 16bit.
- **03** Start Entry point address, to register the initial CS:IP address in 0x86 architecture.
- **04** Extended Linear Address, to specify 32bit addresses.  This specifies the upper 16bit address part of 00 registers.
- **05** Start Entry point Linear Address.  This is the 32 bit linear entry point address.

Then comes n bytes (n is the value of the first field) of data (hex coded) to be loaded and finally a checksum byte (the sum in two's complement of all the record bytes from the colon up).

Comment: So what do you propose for me? I was using `st-flash write bingotfromhex.bin 0x8000000`. I am actually learning openOCD little steps so I can upload *.elf files.  Thanks for explaining how hex files work!

Comment: I don't know.  Intel hex format is a general, very extended format.  I don't work with ARMs.  I cannot give you much more help.  Sorry.  Perhaps you have to use an option for st-flash to be able to parse hex files... Have you tried st-flash --help ???

Comment: It is ok. c: Anyway knowledge you gave me can be very useful. Thanks for help!

Comment: I'm searching for st-flash utility documentation, but no results yet.

Comment: And yes, I have tried `st-flash --help` but it seems it is not working with files other than hex. I couldn't find anything interesting in internet about it, too.

Comment: https://tjakubowski.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/programming-stm32f4-discovery-board-under-linux/  (it seems to work with `.hex` files)

Comment: That's actually interesting because if I try to upload hex file my evaluation board just stops working. Simply it doesn't work. ;( Maybe it's toolchain's fault - guy in tutorial is using Code Sourcery. As I told you before I'm trying to understand openOCD so I wrote simple perl script to make it easier and faster, and it works. I will probably create also simple GUI app in python for openOCD... Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I present a function below to allow this:

```bash
hex2bin path/to/myfirmware1.hex
hex2bin path/to/myfirmware1.hex path/to/myfirmware2.hex
hex2bin myfirmware1.hex myfirmware2.hex myfirmware3.hex myfirmware4.hex
# etc.
```

Note: get the latest versions of my `hex2bin` and `hex2xxdhex` functions in my [eRCaGuy_dotfiles](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/tree/master) repo here: [.bash_useful_functions](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/home/.bash_useful_functions).

### Bash function to mass-convert Intel `*.hex` firmware files to `*.bin` firmware files, and to `*.xxd.hex` files for comparison in `meld`

To add onto [@A. Genchev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37226481/4561887): I find it tedious to have to have such a long command when I want to convert many hex files at once, so I wrote this helper function.

Copy and paste this into the bottom of your `~/.bashrc` file, then run `. ~/.bashrc` to [re-source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62626515/4561887) your `~/.basrhc` file and make this function available to you:

```bash
# Function to convert .hex firmware files to .bin
#
# Example usage:
#
#       # this produces "path/to/myfile.bin" from "path/to/myfile.hex"
#       hex2bin path/to/myfile.hex
#
#       # you can pass multiple paths at once too
#       hex2bin path/to/myfile1.hex path/to/myfile2.hex path/to/myfile3.hex
#
hex2bin() {
    # treat all input args as file paths
    for filepath_hex in "$@"; do
        # See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/965072/4561887
        filepath_hex_no_extension="${filepath_hex%.*}"
        filepath_bin="${filepath_hex_no_extension}.bin"
        # debugging
        # echo "filepath_hex_no_extension = $filepath_hex_no_extension"
        # echo "filepath_bin = $filepath_bin"
        echo "Converting \"$filepath_hex\" to \"$filepath_bin\"."

        objcopy --input-target=ihex --output-target=binary \
            "$filepath_hex" "$filepath_bin"
    done
}

# (Optional) add an alias prefixed with your initials so you can find all your
# custom aliases and functions easily by typing your initials followed by an
# underscore and hitting Tab Tab.
alias gs_hex2bin="hex2bin"
```

If you have a different toolchain, just replace `objcopy` with the version of `objcopy` from your toolchain. Ex: for the [Microchip MPLAB XC32](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/tools-resources/develop/mplab-xc-compilers) compiler toolchain for PIC microcontrollers, use `xc32-objcopy` instead of `objcopy`.

Now, instead of this:

```bash
objcopy --input-target=ihex --output-target=binary \
    path/to/myfirmware1.hex path/to/myfirmware1.bin

objcopy --input-target=ihex --output-target=binary \
    path/to/myfirmware2.hex path/to/myfirmware2.bin
```

...you can do this:

```bash
hex2bin path/to/myfirmware1.hex path/to/myfirmware2.hex
```

You can pass in as many pathnames as you want all at once.

### Going further: comparing and analyzing hex/binary file differences using `objcopy`, `xxd`, and `meld`

What if you want to compare two Intel hex firmware files to look for differences? Perhaps two hex firmware images are nearly identical, but differ only in some strings, IP addresses, or timestamps stored inside of them. That would be nice to know.

Here's how:

```bash
# - for "path/to/myfirmware1.hex", produce both "path/to/myfirmware1.bin"
#   and "path/to/myfirmware1.xxd.hex"
# - for "path/to/myfirmware2.hex", produce both "path/to/myfirmware2.bin"
#   and "path/to/myfirmware2.xxd.hex"
hex2xxdhex "path/to/myfirmware1.hex" "path/to/myfirmware2.hex"

# now compare the two `.xxd.hex` output files in `meld`
meld "path/to/myfirmware1.xxd.hex" "path/to/myfirmware2.xxd.hex"
```

Example output in `meld`:

[image]

[image]

Here is the definition of my `hex2xxdhex` function:

```bash
# Function to convert .hex firmware files to .bin and then to a
# human-compare-friendly .xxd.hex, so you can easily compare two files with
# `diff` or `meld`.
# - See my answer here: https://superuser.com/a/1790518/425838
#
# Example usage:
#
#       # this produces both "path/to/myfile.bin" and "path/to/myfile.xxd.hex"
#       # from "path/to/myfile.hex"
#       hex2xxdhex path/to/myfile.hex
#
#       # you can pass multiple paths at once too
#       hex2xxdhex path/to/myfile1.hex path/to/myfile2.hex
#       # then compare the two output ".xxd.hex" files with `meld`
#       meld path/to/myfile1.xxd.hex path/to/myfile2.xxd.hex
#
hex2xxdhex() {
    # treat all input args as file paths
    for filepath_hex in "$@"; do
        # See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/965072/4561887
        filepath_hex_no_extension="${filepath_hex%.*}"
        filepath_bin="${filepath_hex_no_extension}.bin"
        filepath_xxdhex="${filepath_hex_no_extension}.xxd.hex"
        echo "Converting \"$filepath_hex\" to \"$filepath_bin\" and to"\
            "\"$filepath_xxdhex\"."

        objcopy --input-target=ihex --output-target=binary \
            "$filepath_hex" "$filepath_bin"
        xxd "$filepath_bin" "$filepath_xxdhex"
    done
}
alias gs_hex2xxdhex="hex2xxdhex"
```

For a lot more detail, see my answer here: [Super User: How to compare binary files, hex files, and Intel hex firmware files with `meld`](https://superuser.com/a/1790518/425838)

Answer (score -1):

```bash
arm-none-eabi-objcopy.exe -I ihex file.hex -O binary file.bin
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).