# Appium Doctor - unable to set $JAVA_HOME/bin into PATH variable on MacOS 10.12

Tags: java, bash, path, appium, java-home

Installed appium doctor with npm on MacOS 10.12, and it gives me one error:

```
WARN AppiumDoctor ✖ Bin directory for $JAVA_HOME is not set.
```

I've tried everything I could so far, please help.
Here is my .bash_profile:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/sergei/Library/Android/sdk/"
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export M2_HOME="/Users/sergei/Desktop/1246702 Sergio/apache-maven-3.3.9"
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$M2:$PATH
export JYTHON_HOME="/Users/sergei/jython2.7.0/"
export JYTHON=JYTHON_HOME/bin
export PATH=JYTHON:$PATH

export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

Comment: solved it on my own

Comment: Can you post your solution?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I removed double quotes from the paths and slashes from the end
This is working fine for me now:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/sergei/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 16):

I needed to add

`export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH`

to ~/.bash_profile and restart the terminal

Comment: Make sure that JAVA_HOME doesn't have a trailing slash `/` on the end of the path, that's what caused an error for me as well.

Answer (score 8):

This looks to be an old post, but for future viewers, I found [this solution](https://discuss.appium.io/t/appium-doctor-unable-to-set-java-home-bin/12902/2) better due to it doesn't hardcode java sdk path.

```
JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 5):

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 2):

For me After Adding `JAVA_HOME` and `ANDROID_HOME` in `~/.bash_profile`
file as `export` and in `PATH`

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Library/YourUserName/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools"

export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

in your terminal just type this

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

**Still I need to re-start the Appium server then it worked.**

> **But Appium has given the easy feature to save the user time**
>
> **Open** the **Appium app** and then You can ***Click on*** the **`"Edit Configurations"`** Button 
> A dialog/pop window will appear and where you can add two parameter

- **ANDROID_HOME**
- **JAVA_HOME**

> path(same as above) in the editText. then Click on **`"Save and Restart"`**
>
> again click on **`"restart now"`** button in the pop window and 
> you are done once Appium is restarted an up and
>
> no need to deal with bash_profile or any command

Comment: Thank you! For some reason, Appium couldn't read JAVA_HOME path from my bash_profile but from Edit Configuration menu the field was empty and when I pasted /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home it started to work.

Comment: What is the "Appium app?" I've installed Appium and there are nothing but command line tools.

Answer (score 1):

I was making a rookie mistake and want to add it here so people dont repeat my mistake.

Instead of exporting $PATH and $JAVA_HOME, i was sourcing it from my /etc/environment file. As a result both showed up correct when I would use echo but my Appium install could not find it.

Then i found this out : [Unix: What is the difference between source and export?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474650/unix-what-is-the-difference-between-source-and-export)

Basically you gotta export the variables from your bashrc so they get added to your global environment and appium can then access it.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of correct answers should be working for someone and for not for some.

I recommend trying solution form official developer support.

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/j2sdk1.5.0

export JAVA_HOME

PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH;

export PATH
```

try this should work like a charm.
[https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19575-01/820-5019/ghhls/index.html][1]

Answer (score 1):

My problem was I forgot to close the terminal and restart it. When you finish adding the `JAVA_HOME/Bin` to PATH in the environment variables click OK and close and don't forget to also close all your terminals.

After opening your terminal again, it should be updated and running appium-doctor will see the updated Environmental variable.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is to add C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin to your PATH variable.

It's not complaining about JAVA_HOME, it just wants the bin directory adding to path.

Afterwards restart your command line as administrator.
I realize this is for Windows, but I think it's the same problem as I was getting.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving the solution here, incase anyone faced similar problem in Mac Catalina, when running Appium C# script to initialise Android driver. Tried fixing .bash_profile and .zprofile files as mentioned in many answers, nothing seem to work.

Then, decided to explicitly set ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME environment variables programmatically as follows, before initialising Android driver, it finally worked:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ANDROID_HOME", "/Users/{username}/Library/Android/sdk");
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME", "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home");
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried different things, everything was ok, but this file "Bin directory of $JAVA_HOME is not set" stayed. After that i wrote `npm uninstall appium-doctor` in bash, and after that everything was ok... you can try uninstall, then `npm install appium-doctor`

Answer (score 0):

macOS Mohave, v.10.14.6.

1. vim ~/.bash_profile
2. export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home

   export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 0):

There is a settings menu in the Appium GUI ("Edit configurations" on Mac) where you can enter the path. This is what fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Terminal:vim .bash_profile
`export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/sharadgupta/Documents/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`

Add only above 4 lines

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and thanks for your contribution! This is an answer to an already answered question. Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

## Android and JAVA path setup for Appium for Mac:

Open Terminal and type `vi ~/.profile` (If super user permission needed use sudo)-> This will open profile file.

click `i` or `insert` button for edit the file.
add below contents to the .profile file(Change Android Home based on your SDK installation path):

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/<userdirectory>/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Click ESC button and `:wq` and Enter (Will save the changes and quit the file.)

In Terminal type: `source ~/.profile`  (To apply changes to the `.profile` file)

### Test Configuration:

In Terminal type: `$echo JAVA_HOME` (Check the output, and test other values we configured in `.profile` file)

Now run again to find the status: `appium-doctor --android`

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the system! I had the same issue and it got solved.
I have even had other issues with appium that got solved again by restarting.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the complete path i.e /Users/'your name'/Library/.......

This is what worked for me.