# Robotframework Appium - JAVA_HOME is not set currently

Tags: java, macos, appium, robotframework, java-home

I've created a similar test on my windows machine and i've set JAVA_HOME in my environment variables.

Now I am trying to do this on my MacOS. When typing echo $JAVA_HOME I do get a response

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home`

When I'm trying to run my test I get this error message saying I have to set JAVA_HOME. What am I doing wrong?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzgdY.png)

Comment: edit your bash profile, export the variables, more info here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40231125/appium-doctor-unable-to-set-java-home-bin-into-path-variable-on-macos-10-12/56511504#56511504

Comment: Please don't post a picture of errors. They aren't searchable or copyable, and the visually empaired can't read them at all.