# Display float axis labels with dots instead of commas

Tags: plot, xmgrace

Is it possible to display the axis labels on a xmgrace plot as 0.5 instead of 0,5, which is what I get by default?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You need to set your machine's locale so that it uses the right decimal separator. From the command line just use

`LC_ALL=C xmgrace`

or [set up an alias](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/create-aliases/).

Have a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845638/how-do-i-change-the-decimal-separator-in-the-printf-command-in-bash) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This other option worked for me:

If digital marks are wrong (“,” instead of “.”), type export **LC_NUMERIC=C** at the terminal xmgrace is run from.

I found here: https://ddcampayo.wordpress.com/2008/10/16/xmgrace/