# Format currency in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

Is it possible to format currency in Bash?

Example data is received as
`19366`
Data to be displayed as
`$193,66`

Thanks.

Comment: `printf "%.2f \n" $((19366/100))` works fine.

Comment: Actually this does not work as it is rounding off.

Answer (score 4):

Simply handle your value as a text string, instead of a number, and insert a dollar sign and a comma at the correct positions:

```bash
$ v=19366
$ printf '$%s,%s\n' "${v:0: -2}" "${v: -2}"
$193,66
```

`${v:offset:length)` expands as the substring of `$v` that starts at character `offset` (counting from `0`) and which length is `length`. But negative offsets and lengths can be used to refer to the end of the string.

`${v:0:-2}` expands as the substring of `$v` that starts at the beginning (`0`) and which length is the number of remaining characters minus two (`-2`). In our example this is `193`.

`${v: -2}` expands as the substring of `$v` that starts two characters before the end (`-2`) and which length (not specified) is the number of remaining characters. In our example this is `66`. Note the space between `:` and `-2`, it is needed to avoid another interpretation by the shell (providing default value `2` if `v` is unset or null).

Comment: Have a look at bottom of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72796093/1765658), there is a coma! `$12.345,67`

Comment: Yes, fine. I wasn't suggesting that your answer is incorrect. I simply remark that the OP want a comma, nothing else. So there is no need for complicated things involving the locale. Just insert a comma in the right place and voilà.

Comment: Hardcoding *`decimal separator`* is not portable! Using *locale*  is a recommendable good practice.

Comment: OK, forget it, it's not very important.

Comment: ( I disagree: Trying to use good practice by habit, is important! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

**Preamble** In your request, you use coma `,` as decimal separator (radix mark). For locale support, see second part of my answer.

### 1. Pseudo floating poing using integer as strings

I often use this kind of *pseudo float*:

```bash
amount=123456
amount=00$amount # avoid bad length error
printf '$%.2f\n' ${amount::-2}.${amount: -2}
```

```
$1234.56
```

```bash
for amount in  0 1 12 123 1234 12345;do
    amount=00$amount
    printf '$%.2f\n' ${amount::-2}.${amount: -2}
done
```

```
$0.00
$0.01
$0.12
$1.23
$12.34
$123.45
```

#### As a function:

```bash
int2amount() { 
    if [[ $1 == -v ]]; then
        local -n _out="$2"
        shift 2
    else
        local _out
    fi
    local _amount=00$(($1))
    printf -v _out $'$%\47.2f' ${_amount::-2}.${_amount: -2}
    [[ ${_out@A} != _out=* ]] || echo "$_out"
}
```

Then

```bash
int2amount 123456
```

```
$1’234.56
```

```bash
int2amount -v var 1234567
echo $var
```

```
$12’345.67
```

### 2. Remark regarding *locale*, decimal separator and thousand separators

In your request, your *radix mark* is a coma **`,`**. This depend on your ***locale configuration***. U could hit something like:

```bash
set | grep ^LC\\\|^LANG
```

to show how this is configured on your host.

As there are many issues regarding locales, I've asked [How to determine which character is used as decimal separator or thousand separator under current locale](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72798358/1765658) as separated question.

Try:

```bash
for locvar in   C    en_US.UTF-8    de_DE.UTF-8   ;do
    LC_NUMERIC=$locvar int2amount 1234567
done
```

```
$12345.67
$12,345.67
bash: line 1: printf: 0012345.67: invalid octal number
$12.345,00
```

Error because unsing `de_DE` locale configuration, you have to use a coma as separator ([Decimal separator at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator)).

This is already know to produce issues using `bc`: [How do I change the decimal separator in the printf command in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62552336/1765658)

### Final function unsing variable *`decimal separator`*

```bash
int2amount () {
    if [[ $1 == -v ]]; then
        local -n _out="$2"
        shift 2
    else
        local _out
    fi
    local _amount=00$(($1)) _decsep
    printf -v _decsep %.1f 1
    _decsep=${_decsep:1:1}
    printf -v _out '$%'\''.2f' ${_amount::-2}${_decsep}${_amount: -2}
    [[ ${_out@A} != _out=* ]] || echo "$_out"
}
```

```bash
for locvar in   C    en_US.UTF-8    de_DE.UTF-8   ;do
    LC_NUMERIC=$locvar int2amount 1234567
done
```

```
$12345.67
$12,345.67
$12.345,67
```

**Note about `LC_ALL`**: If in your environment, a variable `$LC_ALL` is defined, all demos using `LC_NUMERIC` won't work because `LC_ALL` is over. You have to `unset LC_ALL` or use:

```
LC_ALL=$locvar LC_NUMERIC=$locvar int2amount 1234567
```

in last demo.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `printf`

```
amount="240570.578"
printf "%'.2f\n" $amount
> 240,570.58
```

Comment: This does not work for my example. This is the output
`19,366.00`

Answer (score 0):

`printf` does have a thousands grouping format specifier flag, however the character used to denote the groups (non-monetary grouping character) depends on locale (`LC_NUMERIC`).

The `C` or `POSIX` locale uses *no* grouping character. Therefore you can't do this *portably* with printf.

```
printf "%'d\n" 19366
```

Works if the current locale supports the comma grouping character.

In my bashrc, I use the following function to add thousands groupings to any integer, using comma (`,`) and preserving a non numeric prefix (like `$`, or `-` for negative numbers). It doesn't depend on locale, but does require `rev`.

```
commafy ()
{
    printf %s "${1%%[0-9]*}"
    printf '%s\n' "${1##*[!0-9]}" |
    rev |
    sed -E 's/[0-9]{3}/&,/g; s/,$//' |
    rev
}
```

Example:

```
commafy '$19366'
# gives
$19,366
```

You could slightly simplify this too:

```
printf %s \$
printf '%s\n' 19366 |
rev |
sed -E 's/[0-9]{3}/&,/g; s/,$//' |
rev
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplistically -

```
$: sed -E 's/([0-9]*)([0-9][0-9])$/$\1,\2/'<<<"19366"
$193,66
```

Answer (score 0):

The question actually mixes two different problems:

1. Converting cents to US-Dollar (or Euros, or whatever currency)
2. Using the correct currency format (currency_symbol, mon_decimal_point, mon_thousands_sep, ...)

The first can be solved by using either external tools like `bc` or a shell that supports floating point operations like `ksh`. Bash only supports integer arithmetic.

The latter can be solved by using locale information. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77046244/how-to-determine-currency-symbol-of-current-locale-in-posix-shell-script/77710690#answer-77710690) for an example.