# How to determine which character is used as decimal separator (radix point) or thousand separator, under current locale?

Tags: bash, locale, number-formatting

Comming from [this answer to *`Format currency in Bash`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72796093/1765658), I wonder for ways to determine which characters are used as numeric separators.

There are lot of issue regarding locales and number formating, for sample:

```bash
printf '%.5f\n' $(bc -l <<<'4*a(1)')
3.14159

LANG=de_DE printf '%.5f\n' $(bc -l <<<'4*a(1)')
bash: printf: 3.14159265358979323844: invalid number
3,00000
```

binary calculator `bc` seem not handling locale correctly...

Under mentioned answer, searching for *decimal separator* (or *radix character*), I've used this:

```
int2amount() {
    local TIMEFORMAT=%U _decsep
    read _decsep < <(eval 'time true' 2>&1)
    _decsep=${_decsep//[0-9]}
    ...
}
```

This work fine:

```
pi() { local TIMEFORMAT=%U _decsep;read _decsep < <(eval 'time true' 2>&1);_decsep=${_decsep//[0-9]};
       local pi=$(bc -l <<<'4*a(1)')
       printf '%.5f\n' ${pi/./$_decsep}
}

pi
3.14159
LANG=de_DE pi
3,14159
```

But as *thousand separator* is a lot easier to find:

```
printf -v ts "%'d" 1111 ; ts=${ts//1}
```

There is no fork, so system footprint is very light.

So I could imagine at begin of source file, something like:

```
numericSeparators() {
    local TIMEFORMAT=%U
    read NUM_DEC_SEP < <(eval 'time true' 2>&1)
    NUM_DEC_SEP=${NUM_DEC_SEP//[0-9]}
    printf -v NUM_THO_SEP "%'d" 1111
    NUM_THO_SEP=${NUM_THO_SEP//1}
}
numericSeparators
declare -r NUM_THO_SEP NUM_DEC_SEP
...
```

But I think `<(eval 'time true' 2>&1)` heavy for the goal. I'm searching for a lighter and/or cleaner way for determine them (even both *decimal* and *thousand* separators).

---

Thanks to [dan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72800369/1765658), my functions would become simplier and quicker!

```bash
pi() {
    local _decsep pi=$(bc -l <<<'4*a(1)')
    printf -v _decsep %.1f 1
    printf '%.5f\n' ${pi/./${_decsep:1:1}}
}
```

```bash
pi
3.14159
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 pi
3,14159
```

```bash
numericSeparators() {
    local numtest
    printf -v numtest "%'.1f" 1111
    NUM_THO_SEP=${numtest:1:1}
    NUM_THO_SEP=${NUM_THO_SEP/1}
    NUM_DEC_SEP=${numtest: -2:1}
}
numericSeparators
```

```bash
for loctest in   C   en_US.UTF-8   de_DE.UTF-8   ;do
    LANG=$loctest numericSeparators
    printf '  %-12s decimal: \47%s\47 thousand: \47%s\47\n' \
            "$loctest"  "$NUM_DEC_SEP"  "$NUM_THO_SEP"
done
```

```
  C            decimal: '.' thousand: ''
  en_US.UTF-8  decimal: '.' thousand: ','
  de_DE.UTF-8  decimal: ',' thousand: '.'
```

Comment: `locale decimal_point` for the decimal point, maybe?

Comment: @JamesBrown Oh yes! (forgot this!) ... But `locale` is not builtin, so system footprint won't be better...

Comment: Try `LANG=de_DE printf '%.5f\n' $(LANG=de_DE bc -l <<<'4*a(1)')`, maybe?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet On my system, this render: Error: `bash: printf: 3.14159265358979323844: invalid number`, then `3,00000`.

Comment: My guess is that `bc` ignores the locale while `bash` does not.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I've wrote:  *`for sample: ... binary calculator bc seem not handling locale correctly...`*

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, I missed that, sorry. But even if it was don't you think that `$(LANG=de_DE bc -l <<<'4*a(1)')` would be needed instead of just `$(bc -l <<<'4*a(1)')`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246015/discussion-between-f-hauri-and-renaud-pacalet).

Comment: What's the issue with `printf -v ds %.1f 1; ds=${ds//[10]}` to get decimal separator?

Comment: @dan I'ts too simple for me! Bravo, If you post this as an aswer, I will accept your answer!

Comment: @dan please comme to [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246015/discussion-between-f-hauri-and-renaud-pacalet) back, for tests...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the locale's **radix character** (decimal separator) with:

```
printf -v ds '%#.1f' 1
ds=${ds//[0-9]}
```

And the **thousands grouping separator**, with:

```
printf -v ts "%'d" 1111
ts=${ts//1}
```

Some locales (eg. `C`) have no thousands separator, in which case `$ts` is empty. Conversely, if the radix character is not defined by the locale, POSIX (`printf(3)`) says it should default to `.`. The `#` flag guarantees that it will be printed.

Comment: Then in one way: `LANG=$loczest printf -v var %\'5.1f 1111;thsnd=${var:1:1} radix=${var: -2:1} ;thsnd=${thsnd/1};declare -p thsnd radix`

Answer (score 0):

In the vast majority of cases, you don't even have to know which locale setting you're in to properly decode any value, regardless of your own locale's settings.

Because you simply can't have 2 radix points (RP), of any base, one can just use `gsub()` or similar quick counting tools to figure out which one of `,` vs. `.` has multiple copies.

- If both does, that's likely problematic input to begin with.
- If one of each exists, right side one has to be the RP
- When there's only one and ambiguous, then consider :

> If there's 0 or more digits that's anything but 3 digits to right of that character, it couldn't possibly be the thousands sep

> And more likely than not, thousands sep is bookended on both sides by digits, but having a leading edge or trailing edge radix point isn't all that uncommon

Only the 4 to 6 digit numbers (including below radix point, assuming its' still ambiguous) would require extra context to properly decode.