# File size in human readable format

Tags: linux, bash

Given the size of a file in bytes, I want to format it with **[IEC (binary) prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix)** to **3 [significant figures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) with trailing zeros**, e.g. 1883954 becomes 1.80M.

Floating-point arithmetic isn't supported in bash, so I used awk instead. The problem is I don't how to keep the trailing zeros. Current solution:

```
if [ $size -ge 1048576 ]
then
    size=$(awk 'BEGIN {printf "%.3g",'$size'/1048576}')M
elif [ $size -ge 1024 ]
then
    size=$(awk 'BEGIN {printf "%.3g",'$size'/1024}')K
fi
```

(The files aren't that big so I don't have to consider bigger units.)

Edit: There's another problem with this. See Adrian Frühwirth's comment below.

Comment: It's a bit of a hack, but can you not convert to string, check the length after the decimal and add zeroes as necessary?

Comment: the GNU `ls` command accepts the `-lh` option...

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: not the format I want. 3 s.f. with trailing zeros.

Comment: Assuming a file size of 1048575 that falls into your elif, are you really sure you want this output? `$ echo "1048575" | awk '{ printf "%.3gK\n", $1/1024 }'` => `1.02e+03K`.

Comment: @Adrian Frühwirth: Damn I forgot about that. I was originally working with SI unit, where it wouldn't be a problem, but I decided to be more conventional (this is for indexing files).

Comment: `ls -lah` work for ya?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

[GNU Coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) contains an apparently rather unknown little tool called [`numfmt`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/numfmt-invocation.html#numfmt-invocation) for numeric conversion, that does what you need:

```
$ numfmt --to=iec-i --suffix=B --format="%.3f" 4953205820
4.614GiB
```

I think that suits your needs well, and isn’t as large or hackish as the other answers.

If you want a more powerful solution, look at my other answer.

Comment: @someguy: The `numfmt` of `coreutils-8.22` tells me, that the changes you made are an in an invalid format. Hence there is no result for `1048575`. Using my original format, it works, and the result is `1.0MiB`. So I rolled your changes back. If you have a version that accepts your format, feel free to change it back again, and mention the version.

Comment: @someguy: All I get with your format, is
`numfmt: invalid format „%3g“, the directive must be in the form %['][-][N]f` (Manually translated from German by me.)  
It seems  numfmt` does not support what you want, even though it should. :/  
Maybe give the developers a hint at http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it followed the printf format. Could you change it so that the result is printed to three significant figures with trailing zeroes? Otherwise I can't accept it as the answer.

Comment: You can specify the precision since version 8.24. `numfmt --to=iec-i --suffix=B --format="%.3f" 4953205820` outputs 4.614GiB

Comment: Nicely done. This is how to use if with file-path: `size=$(echo $(numfmt --to=iec-i --suffix=B --format="%.3f" $(stat --format=%s hosts.txt)) | sed -e "s/i//g");` (removing that weird `i`...). I'm using it in my [project](https://github.com/eladkarako/hosts.eladkarako.com).

Comment: @project: If you don't want the 'i' in the prefix, instead of the `--to=iec-i` option, use `--to=iec`.

Comment: is there a way to place a space between the number and the unit. e.g 5 KB instead of 5KB

Comment: @Tim: It doesn't look like there is, unfortunately. You could pipe the output to sed: `... | sed -r 's/([A-Z])/ \1/'`.

Comment: Similar to the @user257319 approach, combining this with @user208145's approach is easy: `numfmt --to=iec --format="%.0f" $(stat -c %s somefile.ext)`. This gives you 24K, 10M etc, without any extra `i` or `B` suffixes.

Answer (score 148):

Is there any reason you are not using

```
ls -lh
```

command ? If you are on a Linux system which has been released in the last few years, you have this functionality.

Comment: Because it doesn't give it in the format I want. Like I said, to 3 significant figures with trailing zeros. The example I gave -- 1883954 -- would become 1.8M with ls, would it not? (It may differ with implementations but that's how it is with my system.)

Comment: Parsing the size from that is a *serious* mess. Don’t do that!

Comment: This is the perfect answer.

Comment: @xtheking: I understand it's the 'perfect answer' for a lot of people, but it doesn't actually answer my question. It also has its problems as Evi1M4achine mentioned. Admittedly, it's my fault for titling the question so broadly. I decided to leave it so that people can still find answers like this, though.

Comment: Per this answer (not OP question) `ls -lh ~/.bashrc | cut -d ' ' -f 5` >> `101k`

Answer (score 17):

```
ls -lah /path/to/your/file | awk -F " " {'print $5'}
```

Comment: This approach is good. Does not require any 3rd party commands.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you have many files in a folder (ie. > 250,000), would there be a huge penalty to calling `ls`?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `ls` and `awk` to get the file size, use `stat -c %s filename.ext`. It outputs only the number, with nothing else (at least on version 8.21). I can't use `numfmt` because it's an older version which doesn't appear to use the printf syntax with decimal precision. I instead use the script below. I use the last line to test if the script is being sourced. If it's not, I can call it directly on the command line.

```
#!/bin/bash

function getFriendlyFileSize() {
    OUT='/dev/null'
    [ "$#" == 0 ] && echo 'No number given' && return 1
    [ ! $(echo $1 | egrep -i '\-?[0-9]+') ] && echo 'Garbage data' && return 1

    if [ "$1" == '' -o "$1" -lt 0 ] 2>$OUT
    then
            echo '0 B'
            return 1
    else
            FSIZE=$1
    fi

    [ "$2" == '' ] && DECPTS=1 || DECPTS=$2

    KB=1024
    MB=1048576
    GB=1073741824
    TB=1099511627776
    PB=1125899906842624
    EB=1152921504606846976
    LM=9223372036854775807 # bash comparison limit = 2^63-1 (signed int?)

    [ "$FSIZE" -le 0 ] 2>$OUT && echo "0 B" && return
    [ "$FSIZE" -lt $KB ] 2>$OUT && echo "$FSIZE B" && return
    [ "$FSIZE" -lt $MB ] 2>$OUT && echo "$(echo "scale=$DECPTS;$FSIZE/$KB"|bc) KB" && return
    [ "$FSIZE" -lt $GB ] 2>$OUT && echo "$(echo "scale=$DECPTS;$FSIZE/$MB"|bc) MB" && return
    [ "$FSIZE" -lt $TB ] 2>$OUT && echo "$(echo "scale=$DECPTS;$FSIZE/$GB"|bc) GB" && return
    [ "$FSIZE" -lt $PB ] 2>$OUT && echo "$(echo "scale=$DECPTS;$FSIZE/$TB"|bc) TB" && return
    [ "$FSIZE" -lt $EB ] 2>$OUT && echo "$(echo "scale=$DECPTS;$FSIZE/$PB"|bc) PB" && return
    [ "$FSIZE" -le $LM ] 2>$OUT && echo "$(echo "scale=$DECPTS;$FSIZE/$EB"|bc) EB" && return
    [ "$?" -ne '0' ] 2>$OUT && echo "Bad input" && return 1
}

[[ $_ == $0 ]] && getFriendlyFileSize $1 $2
```

Answer (score 3):

I know that it's a little late. But may someone find it useful.

The answer is, simply, to use `%.2f` instead of `%.3g` in your script. ([src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395284/round-a-divided-number-in-bash))

---

Test:

```
#!/bin/bash

size=1883954

if [ $size -ge 1048576 ]
then
    size=$(awk 'BEGIN {printf "%.2f",'$size'/1048576}')M
elif [ $size -ge 1024 ]
then
    size=$(awk 'BEGIN {printf "%.2f",'$size'/1024}')K
fi

echo $size
```

The Output:

```
1.80M
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using `bc` then the following will help do floating point operations. `scale` can changed as per your needs depending on many digits you want to print.

```
size=1883954

if [ $size -ge 1048576 ]
then
    size=$(echo "scale=2;$size/1048576"| bc)M
elif [ $size -ge 1024 ]
then
    size=$(echo "scale=2;$size/1024" | bc)K
fi

echo $size
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have [Qalculate!](http://qalculate.sourceforge.net/) installed (which is awesome by the way),
there’s an easy trick:

```
human_readable="$( qalc -t set "precision $precision" "${in_bytes}B" )"
```

Example:

```
$ qalc -t -set "precision 3" 5264334820B
5.26 GB
```

It’s a very very powerful tool to have in shell scripting, as it can even simplify formulas, solve for unknowns, and many many more things.

```
$ qalc -t "e^(i*x)=-1"
x = 3.1415927
```

If you want a simpler, less heavy-weight solution, look at my other answer.