# Compare round half up numbers

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Compare the [round half up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_up) values of `num1=172` and `num2=172.8`, where  `num2`'s value will be `173`.

**Print whether or not num1 and num2 are equal.**

```
if (( $(echo "$num1 == $num2" | bc -l) )); then
 echo "num1 and num2 are equal"
else
 echo "number are not close to each other'
fi
```

Comment: You want to round a number to a whole number and compare them then? What is "roundoff" and "roundoff 5" (why 5?) ?

Comment: I mean if 172.1= round of value is 172, incase if decimal  5 & >5 like 172.5,172.6,172.7, etc should be 173.. round of 5 indicate value  5 and >5

Comment: `ncase if decimal 5` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_the_nearest_integer

Answer (score 2):

Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming . Your problem consist of:

- rounding numbers to zero decimal digits
- comparing the results

The first part can be found on stackoverflow, like [Round a divided number in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395284/round-a-divided-number-in-bash) , the second part can be done with just `==` even with string comparison.

```
round() {
    printf "%.${2:-0}f" "$1"
}
num1=172
num2=172.8 
if (( $(round "$num1") == $(round "$num2") )); then
    echo "Equal"
else
    echo "Not equal"
fi
```

The `((` arithmetic *expression* is specific to Bash shell.

---

You can compare them in `bc` using the same method. First take a rounding function from
https://github.com/zg/bc/blob/master/code/funcs.bc and then compare the rounded numbers:

```
if (($(bc -l <<EOF
define int(x)   { auto os;os=scale;scale=0;x/=1;scale=os;return(x) }
int($num1) == int($num2)
EOF
   ) )); then
```

Comment: Hmm... the `((...))` arithmetic operator is POSIX. I think you are referring to the [Arithmetic Commands](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression) section where bash allows assignment within `((...))`.

Comment: Arithmetic expansion `$((...))` is POSIX. Arithmetic expansion is replaced by the result of the expression, but exit status is always 0. Arithmetic expression `((...))` is not in POSIX. Arithmetic expression exits with zero/non-zero exit status when the result of expression is non-zero/zero.  In POSIX `if [ "$((...))" -ne 0 ]; then`, in bash just `if (( .. )); then`. :D

Comment: Ooh ... I like it. I'd not thought about the distinguishing quality being the return but that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

No `bash`, no external utils, just pure (ugly) *POSIX* shell code in two functions:

```
rhup () 
{ 
    [ "${1##*.[5-9]*}" ]
    echo "$((${1%%.*}+$?))"
}

req () 
{ 
    a=
    [ "$(rhup "$1")" = "$(rhup "$2")" ] || a="not "
    echo "When rounded half up $1 and $2 are ${a}equal."
}
```

Demo:

```
req 2 3 ; req 2 2.2 ; req 2.4 2.5
```

Output:

```
When rounded half up 2 and 3 are not equal.
When rounded half up 2 and 2.2 are equal.
When rounded half up 2.4 and 2.5 are not equal.
```

---

How it works:

Given a number `rhup` (short for ***r**ound **h**alf **up***) uses shell *[parameter substitution](https://sites.ualberta.ca/dept/chemeng/AIX-43/share/man/info/C/a_doc_lib/aixuser/usrosdev/parameter_subst.htm#AC8A8CF676shar)* to check if a half-up decimal suffix exists.  Then it adds the resulting error code of `0` or `1` to the number's integer prefix and prints the sum.

`req` (short for ***r**hup **eq**ual*) runs `rhup` on two numbers, compares them, if they're not equal, sets `$a` to *"not "*, then prints the desired conditional English sentence.

Neither function does any error checking on the input values.