# how to remove decimal from a variable?

Tags: shell

how to remove decimal place in shell script.i am multiplying MB with bytes to get value in bytes .I need to remove decimal place.

```
ex:-
196.3*1024*1024
205835468.8
expected output
205835468
```

Comment: What shell are you using? bash? csh? ksh? fish?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

*(You did not mention what shell you're using; this answer assumes Bash).*

You can **remove** the decimal values using `${VAR%.*}`. For example:

```
[me@home]$ X=$(echo "196.3 * 1024 * 1024" | bc)
[me@home]$ echo $X
205835468.8
[me@home]$ echo ${X%.*}
205835468
```

Note that this truncates the value rather than rounds it. If you wish to round it, use `printf` as shown in [Roman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8356768/115845).

The `${variable%pattern}` syntax deletes the shortest match of `pattern` starting from tbe *back* of `variable`. For more information, read http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Answer (score 16):

Use printf:

```
printf %.0f $float
```

This will perform rounding. So if `float` is `1.8`, it'll give you `2`.