# BASH rounding float to the nearest tenth

Tags: bash, decimal, rounding

How do you round floats to the nearest tenths using bc. I have a variable called loadMin

```
loadMin=$(uptime | cut -d" " -f14 | cut -c 1-4)
```

which returns the load averages per minute with two decimal places. I.e 0.01 0.02 0.09. I need the number to be rounded to the nearest tenth. For example 0.01 rounded to 0.0 or 1.09 rounded to 1.1

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394988 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why use `bc`? `printf` will happily do that:

```
printf "%.1f" "$loadMin"
```

If you need to put the result in a variable:

```
printf -v variable "%.1f" "$loadMin"
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using the latter; printf -v variable "%.1f" "$loadMin". It successfully rounded these numbers to the nearest tenth:

2.09 to 2.1---
0.09 to 0.1---
2.99 to 3.0

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one go with `awk`:

```
loadMin=$(uptime | awk '{printf "%0.1f", $14}')
```

**Explanation:**

- Instead of using `cut`, use `awk` instead to make these easier
- `awk` delimit on spaces and tabs by default and separates each line into fields.
- `'{printf "%0.1f", $14}'`: print the 14th field as a floating number, rounded to the nearest 1 decimal place.