# round integer if output comes in decimal

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, scripting

#### Bash shell scripting

```
var1=126
var2=16 
var1/var2 = 7.87
```

My requirement is if the output value comes in decimal, then add 1 to the integer i.e in this case `7+1 =8`. How can I do that?

Comment: It seems you are looking for the ceiling function in `bash`. Here are hints how to do so: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394988/get-ceiling-integer-from-number-in-linux-bash)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394988/get-ceiling-integer-from-number-in-linux-bash] People use `awk` or they invoke a script.

Comment: link is dead, unable to view

Comment: Typos, typos, typos.... [Question is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394988/get-ceiling-integer-from-number-in-linux-bash)

Comment: that will do for me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the modulo operator `%`:

```
#! /bin/bash
var1=126
var2=16
(( result = var1 / var2 ))
(( var1 % var2 && ++ result )) # If there's a remainder, add 1 to result.
echo $result
```