# How do I perform this calculation and output it to standard out?

Tags: bash, math, syntax, echo, stdout

I am trying to do this in Bash:

```
read n

echo int(math.ceil((math.sqrt(1 + 8 * n) - 1) / 2))
```

Of course this isn't working syntax but I am just putting it there so you can tell what I am trying to do.

Is there an easy way to actually make this into valid Bash?

Comment: There's certainly no `sqrt` operator in `bash`.

Comment: Do I have to write my own sqrt function?

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but since `(8n + 1)` is odd, then if `sqrt(8n + 1)` is an integral value, it must also be odd. Consequently, subtracting `(1)` and dividing by `(2)` will always be integral. So if `(n)` can be expressed as `k(k + 1)/2` for any integer `(k)`, then the result is an integer. Otherwise, add one to the integer part.

Comment: @BrettHale Yes, definitely one way around it; wanted to generalize though so in the future if I wanted to compute sqrt's I'd be able to

Comment: And my comment doesn't really help, since finding that `(k)` value is essentially the same as your original problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you ask to do this in Bash, there's no native support for functions like square root or ceiling. It would be simpler to delegate to Perl:

```
perl -wmPOSIX -e "print POSIX::ceil((sqrt(1 + 8 * $n) - 1) / 2)"
```

---

Alternatively, you could use `bc` to calculate the square root, and some Bash to calculate the ceiling.

Let's define a function that prints the result of the formula with `sqrt` of `bc`:

```
formula() {
    local n=$1
    bc -l <<< "(sqrt(1 + 8 * $n) - 1) / 2"
}
```

The `-l` flag changes the `scale` from the default 0 to 20.
This affects the scale in the display of floating point results.
For example, with the default zero, `10 / 3` would print just 3.
We need the floating point details in the next step to compute the ceiling.

```
ceil() {
    local n=$1
    local intpart=${n%%.*}
    if [[ $n =~ \.00*$ ]]; then
        echo $intpart
    else
        echo $((intpart + 1))
    fi
}
```

The idea here is to extract the integer part,
and if the decimal part is all zeros, then we print simply the integer part,
otherwise the integer part + 1, as that is the ceiling.

And a final simple function that combines the above functions to get the result that you want:

```
compute() {
    local n=$1
    ceil $(formula $n)
}
```

And a checker function to test it:

```
check() {
    local n num
    for n; do
        num=$(formula $n)
        echo $n $num $(compute $n)
    done
}
```

Let's try it:

```
check 1 2 3 4 7 11 12 16 17
```

It produces:

```
1 1.00000000000000000000 1
2 1.56155281280883027491 2
3 2.00000000000000000000 2
4 2.37228132326901432992 3
7 3.27491721763537484861 4
11 4.21699056602830190566 5
12 4.42442890089805236087 5
16 5.17890834580027361089 6
17 5.35234995535981255455 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bc`'s `sqrt` function.

```
echo "(sqrt(1 + 8 * 3) - 1) / 2" | bc
```

`Ceil` function can be implemented using any of the methods described in this answer.

[Getting Ceil integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394988/get-ceiling-integer-from-number-in-linux-bash)

For eg:

```
  ceiling_divide() {
      ceiling_result=`echo "($1 + $2 - 1)/$2" | bc`
    }
```

Comment: If I correctly implemented what you wrote, your formula fails for values of n like 4, 7, 11, 12, 16, 17...

Answer (score 1):

You can use bc for all the job

```
$>cat filebc

print "Enter a number\n";
scale=20
a=read()
b=((sqrt(1 + 8 * a) - 1) / 2)
scale=0
print "ceil = ";
((b/1)+((b%1)>0))
quit
```

Call it like that

```
bc -q filebc
```