How to get diff time in github actions job steps
I would like to find the difference between the time of today's date and the time of the date on which PR was generated within the githubactions jobs steps.
What should I do?
jobs:
  pr-comment:
    runs-on: [self-hosted]
    steps:
      - name: Get diff hours
        id: diff_hours
        run: |
          echo "hours= new Date - context.payload.pull_request.created_at" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT // I don't know how to useing date format
      - if: steps.diff_hours.outputs.hours > 24
        name: Test. action
        run: ...


Does this answer your question? Get current time in seconds since the Epoch on Linux, Bash

context.payload.pull_request.created_at is string, so that you can't just use it to calculate time difference.
Time Difference Calculation:
Main Idea is to turn both the current datetime and pr datetime to Epoch time (seconds since 1970) and calculate the difference.
# Get the current date in seconds
current_date_seconds=$(date +%s)

# Convert the custom date to seconds
custom_date_seconds=$(date -d '2023-01-01' +%s)

# Calculate the difference in seconds
difference_seconds=$((current_date_seconds - custom_date_seconds))

# Convert the difference to hours
difference_hours=$((difference_seconds / 3600))

In Github Actions yaml format

run |
echo "difference_in_hours=$(( ( $(date +%s) - $(date -d ${{ github.event.pull_request.created_at }} +%s) ) / 3600 ))" >>  "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"

Note:
You can't access GitHub variables as it is, you should use ${{ variabme_name }} format.
Useful links:
Defining outputs for jobs

Thank you sir,
I would like to know the time difference between the two dates by rounding up.
What should I do?

@user3871177 for rounding up the division on Bash, please refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12536521/22606938
